# Launching an Activity from IME to Add Text (Android)

Tags: android, ime

I'm trying to create a custom keyboard on Android with one additional button which would launch an activity (in this case listening to the user speaking) and convert that into text, similar to how Google's speech recognition button works.

I've created the custom keyboard (using the [SoftKeyboard](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html) demo from the Android developers page) and clicking on my added button launches the voice listening activity fine, and when I log the results they come out correct. However when I try to do something like this:

```
getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(result, 1); //result is a String
```

within the activity, I get no result. I've made sure `getCurrentInputConnection()` is not `null`, and that the editor type (when calling `getCurrentInputEditorInfo()`) is not of type `null` so I know I can enter text as a string and not just character by character (as is suggested [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html)).

I understand that the problem may be that I have no access to the input connection within my new launched activity, but as I've found in other places and here, `startActivityForResult` does not work from `InputMethodServices`.

Basically is there any way to influence the text displayed from my newly launched activity or any way to set up a listener to change the text once the activity finishes?

Thanks for any help you guys have.

Answer (score 0):

gogisha,

I had a similar idea. The activity would be a list of text strings to inject into the document the ime was working on.  Here's how I did it.

In the manifest, I added an activity:

```
    <activity
        android:name="org.this_voice.prakeyboard.KeyboardMacros"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:label="@string/keyboardmacros"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

Then in the ime, I pick up the escape-char code to start the activity:

```
    } else if (primaryCode == 27) {         
        Intent i = new Intent(this, KeyboardMacros.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.putExtra("MODE","okay");
        startActivity(i);
```

But there was a problem with the ime starting the activity in onCreate. Maybe an Android bug/feature.  So I put this in the activity's onCreate:

```
    Intent origin = this.getIntent();
    String okay = origin.getStringExtra("MODE");
    if ((okay == null) || (!okay.matches("okay"))){ finish(); }
```

So, activity only starts when I hit the soft key that sends 27 (Esc). Activity starts, list appears, user chooses an item of text, and the activity loads that into the clipboard:

```
            String macro = dbs.get(result);
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) 
                getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            clipboard.setText(macro);
            finish();
```

And so we fall back into the editor with our ime. So in ime.startInput we have:

```
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    if (clipboard.hasText()){
        getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(clipboard.getText(), 1);
        clipboard.setText("");
```

Clearing the clipboard is important. I'm using setText so that we are compatible from Android 8+. It changed with 11 to fancier stuff.  Oh,
and in the ime onCreate, we clear the clipboard as well:

```
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    clipboard.setText("");
```

Hope this helps. Actually, I hope you figured this out already since you asked your question a year ago....
Best fishes.